# Make associative array key values become index

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$my_array = [
    0 => [
        'id': 123
        'value': 'Val 1'
    ],
    1 => [
        'id': 456
        'value': 'Val 2'
    ],
    2 => [
        'id': 789
        'value': 'Val 3'
    ]
];
```

I would like to index the array with the values of id key in each sub array so that the array becomes:

```
$my_array = [
    123 => [
        'id': 123
        'value': 'Val 1'
    ],
    456 => [
        'id': 456
        'value': 'Val 2'
    ],
    789 => [
        'id': 789
        'value': 'Val 3'
    ]
];
```

I know I can do this with a loop, but isn't there php function(s) that allow me to do this in less lines of codes??

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2):

A call to [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) is sufficient for this task.

```
$arrWithIdAsKey = array_column($my_array, null, 'id');
```

The column_key parameter is NULL here. See the explanation in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this (c.f [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-column.php), [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-combine.php)) :

```
$new_array = \array_combine(\array_column($my_array, 'id'), $my_array);

var_dump($new_array);
// output 
// array(3) {
//   [123]=>
//   array(2) {
//     ["id"]=>
//     int(123)
//     ["value"]=>
//     string(5) "Val 1"
//   }
//   [456]=>
//   array(2) {
//     ["id"]=>
//     int(456)
//     ["value"]=>
//     string(5) "Val 2"
//   }
//   [789]=>
//   array(2) {
//     ["id"]=>
//     int(789)
//     ["value"]=>
//     string(5) "Val 3"
//   }
// }
```